# Adding a forced delay to ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I am looking to capture a stream with ffmpeg and then relay it to something else in nodejs. The problem is, the host i will be using will sometimes lag and I would like to prevent this by adding a forced delay. Is this possible with ffmpeg or will I have to add this in with code?